# extract last word from string only if more than one word R

Tags: r, string, character

I'm having a slight issue with extracting a word from a character string. I have a column that is the taxon name for a species *"Genus species"*. I was trying to create a new column with just the species. Initially I just used

```
library(stringr)
count$species  <- word(count$taxon_name, 2)
```

to extract the second word. This worked great until I realized there are a few entries in the `taxon_name` column that have a parenthesis word between the genus and species, like so, *"Genus (word) species"*.

To remove that I wrote this code, which worked great removing the parantehsis from the entries that had that extra word:

```
count$new_taxon <- gsub("\\([^()]*\\)", "", count$taxon_name)
```

and then performed the above on the new column

```
count$species  <- word(count$new_taxon, 2)
```

That still works on all the ones that haven't been altered, but if an entry had a  parenthesis removed it just leaves the entry blank, and doesn't extract anything. I think it might be recognizing the space as a word? I tried changing around whether the column was a factor or character column and it didn't make a difference. Any suggestions?

NOTE: Essentially there are three types of input in the taxon_name column 
(1) Genus species 
(2) Genus and 
(3) Genus (word) species.

When I try anything that extracts the last word, it deals with case (1) and (3) but now it includes (2) which I just want to be NA, because it doesn't have a species.

Comment: When you use a function not in `base R` such as `word` you shpould start the scipt with a call to `library` or at least say from which package it comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following.

```
x <- c("Genus species", "Genus", "Genus (word) species")
y <- gsub(".*[[:blank:]](\\w+)$", "\\1", x)
is.na(y) <- y == "Genus"
y
[1] "species" NA        "species"
```

Note that it should be very difficult to search for `"species"` since we don't have a full list of them. That's why I've opted by this, to set the elements of the result `y` to `NA` if they are equal to `"Genus"`.

Comment: the problem with this is that it is including when an input is just one word. So essentially there are three types of input in the taxon_name column (1) *Genus species* (2) *Genus* and (3) *Genus (word) species*. When I try anything that extracts the last word, it deals with case (1) and (3) but now it includes (2) which I just want to be NA, because it doesn't have a species. if that makes sense?

Comment: @AllyD And it always starts with `"Genus"`?

Comment: ya it always has `"Genus"`

Comment: oh sorry, I should've specified. It always has a Genus written but not the word Genus, it changes for each entry

Comment: @AllyD OK, if you have a vector of possible `Genus`, use something like `is.na(y) <- y %in% Genus`, but you will need to have such a vector. If not, how can anyone tell which is a genus and which is a species?

Comment: this worked perfect, I just had to create a vector of unique Genus from another column and it filtered out everything, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "species" is never multiple words, you can do it like this:

```
count$species <- gsub("^.*\\s(\\w+)$", "\\1", count$taxon_name)
```

The pattern `(\\s(\\w+)$` means match a space, then multiple word characters, then the end of the string, in otherwords, it matches the last word of the string. Then we replace with capture group 1 using `\\1`

Live example:

https://regex101.com/r/toJeTg/1

Comment: when I try this, it is just removing all the spaces, and clumping them into one giant word, maybe I'm initiating it wrong?

Comment: @AllyD Thanks, try it again now, I made a change.

Comment: hey this works, but now I'm having the same issue, where it is not filling in NA if the `taxon_name` originally entry was just *Genus* if that makes sense?

Comment: @AllyD I would just use a second `gsub` expression here: `gsub("Genus", NA, count$species)`